# Firebase Phone Auth opening reCAPTCHA Page before sending OTP

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I am implementing Firebase Phone Authentication in my React Native Application but after implementing it it is opening reCAPTCHA page to verify I am not a robot before sending me a OTP which is kind of annoying and i have already added SHA-1 and SHA-256 to my google firebase console and also linked my play console to my google cloud console So to remove this reCAPTCHA I was using Android Device Verification API in my previous application but now it is Depricated and I don't know how to use Play Integrity API can you guys help me explaining setp by step setup of Play Integrity API so this reCAPTCHA thing wont appear
[image: package.json file]
[image: android/app dependencies]

I tried using @react-native-firebase/app-check module according to its documentation but its not working for me or may I have not implemented it properly

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Google Play Integrity API (former SafetyNet Attestation API) - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

Comment: Already tried this but still the reCAPTCHA is showing

Comment: Are you using an actual device or emulator?
Did you check that Google Play Service is installed on the device you are using?

Comment: I am using real device and yes Google pay services is installed in it

Comment: Any updates? I'm having the same issue with react-native-firebase 18.5.0.